# Laplace-Beltrami operator expression

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

In the book Shape and Shape Theory of Kendall in p.147 I found the following expression of the Laplace-Beltrami operator: $\sum_i\left({v_i^2-\nabla_{v_i}v_i}\right)$ where $v_i$ are orthonormal tangent vectors. So please what does the exponent 2 stands for?

Thank you

Comment: This is probably explain in the book, but see my answer below.


Answer (score 7):

The $v_i$ are vector *fields*, and as such are derivations. The square usually means that you apply it twice (so, e.g. in the Euclidean space one can take $v_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ and its square is simply $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}$).

Comment: Thank you Mr. Benoît for that consideration.
Actually in the book shape and shape theory I'am supposed to know this definition of Laplace-Beltrami operator, yet I do not know it though I do know other commun definitions of the $\Delta$ operator.
Actually up to now I assimilated $v_i^2$ to the directional derivative of $v_i$ in the direction of $v_i$, the problem is  that when $v_i$ is a vector field, both directional derivative $v_i^2$ and the covariant derivative $\nabla_{v_i}v_i$ are identical and then $\sum_i\left(v_i^2-\nabla_{v_i}v_i\right)$ reduces to zero. 
Thank you again
